Entity Creation and Splitting to a new entity
So, I have a Create Module of an entity, This entity are boxes and they contain 5 bottles. The create module is based on boxes arrivals and I need to split those boxes into 5 bottles(new entity) to send it to different processes. How can I do it? Please help
I tried to Switch the create module to entitys of bottles, batch it into 5 so it can be boxes and split it with separate to have the bottles again but thats not the way to do it since according to the data. Boxes arrive exponentially, not bottles
